# Why my explorer.exe is crashing every second after starting windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash

After I start my laptop, the explorer.exe process keeps crashing and restarting forever.
I tried to boot the system in clean boot state, but the problem persists.
After that, I tried to look in the event viewer program, and these are the errors I can spot  :

[image]

[image]

Could you please point me to the origin for this problem ?
Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 3):

It is caused by DLL module loaded into explorer `C:\Program Filex (x86)\Nuance\PDF Reader\Bin\PDFCore8_x64.dll`.

I think that module can be disabled by [autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx).

Comment: Where can I find the autoruns utility ? I can't look for it in the windows explorer, it's crashing every second :/ !!

Comment: download http://7-zip.org/download.html and autoruns (link in answer). Unpack it into C:\autoruns by 7-zip and start C:\autoruns\Autoruns.exe from command line.

Comment: If you don't see taskbar, press Ctrl + Shift + Esc, go to File > Run new Task > write CMD and press enter. That open command prompt.

Comment: I can't do anything on my system except using cmd..

Comment: Boot from a linux live usb, rename PDFCore8_x64.dll   to  PDFCore8_x64.dll.bak   exit linux and boot windows.

Comment: You can rename this file in Windows from CMD if you can use it. `ren "C:\Program Filex (x86)\Nuance\PDF Reader\Bin\PDFCore8_x64.dll" "PDFCore8_x64.dll.abc"` Then don't forget to disable or delete entry in Autoruns. Is good practice to remove dead links.

Comment: @mounaim - I thought you said you couldn't get to a command prompt in an earlier comment?

Comment: **except** using cmd. I think means that he can use command line. If he can't use command line he can always do this by Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click Start, click Command Prompt (Admin). Type:

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Nuance\PDF Reader\Bin\PDFCore8_x64.dll"
```

Press Enter. Logoff and login back

Comment: I can't lunch cmd as administrator, because I can't do anything on the UI..that's my problem :/

Comment: Open Task Manager, click File > Run new Task. Check the option "Create this task with administrative privileges". Type `cmd` and click OK.